# Правильная реализация SPA приложения инструментами JAVA EE, JSF, Facelets

Tags: java, веб-программирование, java-ee, jsf

В jsf интегрирован ajax, что позволяет без перезагрузки страницы менять отдельные блоки, соответственно позволяет строить SPA приложения. Реализацию этого процесса я вкратце опишу, для того чтоб показать очевидную избыточность кода. А вопрос будет состоять в том, как добиться того же результата без такого количества лишних файлов и лишнего кода?

Итак, есть приложение, у приложения есть пользователи, у пользователей есть профиль, на странице профиля, пользователь может редактировать свои данные. Ситуация вполне распространенная. Чтоб предоставить пользователям такую возможность нам надо создать следующие xhtml страницы - 
"main" - главная страница приложения.
"main_template" - темплейт который реализует страница main.
"profile" - страница профиля пользователя.
"profile", это не совсем страница, это блок который будет инъецирован в нужное место, ну как в gmail, слева меню, сверху вкладки, а основной блок меняется. 
Давайте посмотрим на код этих страниц -

**"main_template.xhtml"**

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" >
        <h:head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
            <title>MY APP</title>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <ui:insert name="profile">
            
            </ui:insert>
        </h:body>
    </html>
```

**"main.xhtml"**

```html
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/main/main_template.xhtml"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
        <ui:define name="profile">
            <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/main/profile.xhtml" />
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
```

**"profile.xhtml"**

```html
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    
        <h:form>
            <h:outputText value="Name: " />
            <h:outputText value="#{profileController.name}" />
            <p:commandButton value="Edit"  update="@form" immediate="false" />
        </h:form>

    </ui:composition>
```

Как видно из "profile.xhtml" мы выводим имя пользователя обращаясь за ним к profileController.name, у нас даже есть кнопочка, но она ничего не делает, с ней разберемся позже. Давайте пока реализуем ProfileController.java -

**ProfileController.java**

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class ProfileController implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    PersonManager personManager;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        PersonEntity person = personManager.getPersonByLogin("Михаил876");
        this.name = person.getName();
    }

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Как видите, у нас есть некий PersonManager.java который уже умеет брать данные из базы и выдает нам сущность Пользователя во время инициализации бина. 
Ок, пока все классно, но теперь мы хотим предоставить пользователю возможность редактировать свои данные, у нас и кнопочка для этого имеется. Для этого нам нужно в нашем ProfileController.java создать специальный метод, пускай будет просто saveName() -

**ProfileController.saveNewData()**

```
public void saveName(){
    //Мы берем значение переменной name
    //и используем наш personManager
    //чтоб сделать запись в базу нового имени
}
```

Отлично! Так как у нас приложение в стиле SPA, нам надо без перезагрузки страницы предоставить пользователю поле, в которое он может вписать новое значение своего имени. Надо в блоке "profile.xhmtl" заменить этот блок -

```html
<h:outputText value="#{profileController.name}" />
<p:commandButton value="Edit"  update="@form" immediate="false" />
```

Этим -

```html
<p:inputText value="#{profileController.name}" />
<p:commandButton value="Save"  update="@form" immediate="false" />
```

Не удивляйтесь пространству имен p: это у нас подключен [PrimeFaces](https://www.primefaces.org).
Продолжим, для того чтоб заменить один блок другим нам надо, во первых, научить нашу кнопку заменять эти блоки один другим, во вторых вынести эти блоки в отдельные файлы, чтоб ими можно было заменять друг друга. Блок для отображения имени назовем "nameEdit.xhtml", просто потому что в этом блоке надпись на кнопке Edit, и соответственно "nameSave.xhtml".
Выглядеть они будут следующим образом -

**"nameEdit.xhtml"**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

        <h:outputText value="#{profileController.name}" />
    
        <p:commandButton value="Edit" update="@form" immediate="false"
            actionListener="#{profileController.setNamePage('nameSave')}"/>
        
    </ui:composition>
```

**"nameSave.xhtml"**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

        <h:outputText value="#{profileController.name}" />
    
        <p:commandButton value="Save" update="@form" immediate="false"
            actionListener="#{profileController.setNamePage('nameEdit')}" action="#{profileController.saveName()}" />
        
    </ui:composition>
```

Как вы заметили, у нас появился новый метод setNamePage(' '), который мы вызываем по нажатию кнопки, он служит для замены блоков один другим. Как он это делает мы обсудим ниже, ну а пока создадим переменную namePage и гетеры и сетер  к ней-

**ProfileController.namePage**

```
private String namePage;
public String getNamePage() {
    return namePage;
}

public void setNamePage(String namePage) {
    this.namePage = namePage;
}
```

Мы уже у цели, минутку терпения :)
Теперь надо по нажатию на кнопку заменить блок nameEdit.xhtml на nameSave.xhtml, для этого нужно определить местоположение этого блока в блоке profile.xhtml, блок в блоке)) -

**"profile.xhtml"**

```html
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    
        <h:form>
            <h:outputText value="Name: " />
            <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/main/profile/components/#{ProfileController.namePage}.xhtml" />
        </h:form>

    </ui:composition>
```

Видите что получается, мы вместо имени страницы на которой находится блок с полями ввода\вывода имени и кнопкой Редакировать\Сохранить подставляем переменную ProfileController.namePage, а вот в эту переменную мы уже и кладем имя страницы в которой находится нужный нам блок нажатием кнопки и вызовом метода setNamePage(String namePage), и после этого обновляем h:form в котором находится наш блок. После обновления формы мы находим уже другое имя страницы и соответственно загружаем совершенно другой блок. И это все без перезагрузки страницы, благодаря магии AJAX.

Вот, вот и будет сам вопрос, давайте сперваа взглянем на весь код целиком, для наглядности -

**"main_template.xhtml"**

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" >
        <h:head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
            <title>MY APP</title>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <ui:insert name="profile">
            
            </ui:insert>
        </h:body>
    </html>
```

**"main.xhtml"**

```html
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/main/main_template.xhtml"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
        <ui:define name="profile">
            <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/main/profile.xhtml" />
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
```

**"profile.xhtml"**

```html
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    
        <h:form>
            <h:outputText value="Name: " />
            <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/main/profile/components/#{ProfileController.namePage}.xhtml" />
        </h:form>

    </ui:composition>
```

**"nameEdit.xhtml"**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

        <h:outputText value="#{profileController.name}" />
    
        <p:commandButton value="Edit" update="@form" immediate="false"
            actionListener="#{profileController.setNamePage('nameSave')}"/>
        
    </ui:composition>
```

**"nameSave.xhtml"**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

        <h:outputText value="#{profileController.name}" />
    
        <p:commandButton value="Save" update="@form" immediate="false"
            actionListener="#{profileController.setNamePage('nameEdit')}" action="#{profileController.saveName()}" />
        
    </ui:composition>
```

**ProfileController.java**

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class ProfileController implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    PersonManager personManager;
    private String name;
    private String namePage;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        PersonEntity person = personManager.getPersonByLogin("Михаил876");
        this.name = person.getName();
    }

    public void saveName(){
        //Мы берем значение переменной name
        //и используем наш personManager
        //чтоб сделать запись в базу нового имени
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNamePage() {
        return namePage;
    }
    public void setNamePage(String namePage) {
        this.namePage = namePage;
    }
}
```

Вот, теперь когда мы видим ситуацию в целом давайте зададимся вопросом, что это вообще такое, почему для того, чтоб заменить всего две строчки кода мы городим такую конструкцию? Ок, сейчас нам требуется редактировать имя, но ведь есть еще фамилия, имейл, логин, телефон, скайп.... Да можно все редактировать в одном блоке, но не в этом ведь суть, суть в том, что нам надо создать кучу страниц и это только для профиля, почему их нельзя сложить в один файл и дергать от туда нужный блок? Но и это не все, для определения имени страницы в которой находится нужный нам блок, мы передаем строку, что само по себе ненормально, сродни передачи sql команд строкой.

Вот и вопрос, точно ли я ничего не упустил, возможно есть более правильная практика реализации поставленных задач инструментами JAVA EE, JSF, Facelets?

Answer (score 2):

Насколько мне известно, спецификация `JSF` никогда не позиционировалась как решение для создания `SPA`. Несмотря на то, что это **можно** сделать, **нет никаких причин** для того, чтобы это делать.

Основная "среда обитания" `SPA`-приложений - `JavaScript` фреймворки, которые формируют интерфейс прямо в браузере, без необходимости обращения к серверу. Именно поэтому в таких случаях `URL` зачастую не меняется, т.к. не требуется обновление страницы с сервера. Т.е., формат `SPA` - это не какое-то преимущество, а просто констатация факта. Более того, такой формат приносит больше проблем, чем преимуществ (классическая проблема - невозможность сохранить/передать ссылку на конкретную страницу).

В свою очередь Java **Server** Faces - это именно серверная технология, при использовании которой большинство функциональности проходит через сервер. В виду этого, самое прямое и простое решение - использовать отдельный `URL` для каждой страницы ("классический" подход).

Итого:

1. Ответом на Ваш конкретный вопрос могут быть следующие статьи: [SPI with Facelets, Ajax and HTML5](https://www.theserverside.com/tutorial/Creating-a-single-page-inteface-SPI-with-JSF-Facelets-Ajax-and-HTML5); [SPA With BootsFaces](https://www.beyondjava.net/blog/single-page-applications-with-bootsfaces/)
2. Настоятельно не рекомендую использовать технологии не по основному назначению. Если задача - получить `SPA`, используйте другую технологию (например - `GWT`). Если задача - использовать `JSF`, то лучше не строить SPA-интерфейс, а делать вместо этого "классическое" Web-приложение.